# Returning the number of lines in a .txt file

Tags: java, methods, return

This is my debut question here, so I will try to be as clear as I can.

I have a sentences.txt file like this:

> Galatasaray beat Juventus 1-0 last night.
>
> I'm going to go wherever you never can find me.
>
> Papaya is such a delicious thing to eat!
>
> Damn lecturer never gives more than 70.
>
> What's in your mind?

As obvious there are 5 sentences, and my objective is to write a listSize method that returns the number of sentences listed here.

```
public int listSize()
{
// the code is supposed to be here.

return sentence_total;}
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: I see only 5 sentences here.

Comment: Oops! Immediately correcting it.

Comment: could you a few more statements to you method before posting the question and let us know what is the direction of you thoughts?

Comment: What have you tried before asking this question . Could you show some code we could help imrove on ?

Comment: I was confused and couldn't do anything useful

Comment: Why is the method accepting the returned value? Should not accept a File/Path/String route?

Answer (score 2):

To read a file and count its lines, use a `java.io.LineNumberReader`, plugged on top of a `FileReader`. Call `readLine()` on it until it returns `null`, then `getLineNumber()` to know the last line number, and you're done !

Alternatively (Java 7+), you can use the NIO2 `Files` class to fully read the file at once into a `List<String>`, then return the size of that list.

BTW, I don't understand why your method takes that `int` as a parameter, it it's supposed to be the value to compute and return ?

Comment: try this approach, so you learn something on your way, instead of copy past the other one

Comment: My intention was to return that int parameter as the number of sentences. If this is wrong I'm willing to change it after understanding what I should do

Comment: The `int` you accept as a parameter if a primitive type. You can change its value locally inside the method, but that change won't be visible to the method caller afterwards, because Java parameters are passed-by-value (ie. the parameter you see inside the method is a *copy* of the variable passed by the caller). So there is no point in taking that parameter.

Comment: The problem with using `Files.readAllLines()` is that it reads all lines into memory; this may, or may not, be suitable.

Comment: Absolutely. But for such a short file, performance won't be an issue, and the list of strings will be collected as soon as the method returns. Or, with escape analysis, it may as well not be instanciated at all by the JVM. But generally speaking, youre right, it's important to know the difference between the two solutions I mentioned.

Comment: So I delete that int the parameter takes

Comment: Exactly. It is useless here.

Answer (score 1):

Using [LineNumberReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html):

```
LineNumberReader  reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("sentences.txt")));
reader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(reader.getLineNumber() + 1); // +1 because line index starts at 0
reader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to get number of lines in that file..

```
    try {
        File file = new File("filePath");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        int totalLines = 0;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            totalLines++;
        }
        reader.close();
        System.out.println(totalLines);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
```

Comment: this is spoon feeding. and you should avoid this.

Comment: I won't get anything from here before understanding why it is written, so no worries.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
Path file = Paths.getPath("route/to/myFile.txt");
int numLines = Files.readAllLlines(file).size();
```

If you want to limit them or process them lazily:

```
Path file = Paths.getPath("route/to/myFile.txt");
int numLines = Files.llines(file).limit(maxLines).collect(Collectors.counting...);
```

Comment: Yes, but the second version as well?

Comment: No, the second version won't load all into memory. Streams are lazily populated ;)